# Working with CSS and width

Tags: css

My [friends spa website](http://ambergoodwin.com/melt/) I'm making for them is going good however I just have a quick question about CSS. If you resize the page you see the colour of the links change from the grey they are to blue, then red, then green. This is my testing method to know which Media Query I need to work with. I'd like to know why the logo isn't repeating along the top of the page?

I'm trying to have the image repeat and span the full width of the top of the the screen size but instead it's like the width is set to 100px?

Here is my code for the title-area for the media query with the red links:

```
#title-area {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 204px;
    top: 0px;
    background: url(images/melt-logo.jpg) top center repeat;
    text-indent: -99999px;

}
```

I've looked through firebug and can't seem to find the problem.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `#title-area` has a fixed width of 700px. Change this to 100% (approx line 210 in style.css).

The background on it is set to `no-repeat`. The example in your post is more correct - change this to simply `repeat` (approx line 214 in style.css).

`#title-area` also has `left:-350px` set so the logo appears in the left even though it's on the right of logo.jpg. Make the width something like 175% which will cover it up, otherwise the better idea would be to put the logo on the left of the image, set left to 0px and leave the width at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the left value too:

```
#title-area {
    left: 0;
}
```